# PHP: Get values from a column using its name

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Is it possible to get all the values from a database knowing the name of the column? I have a database like this: The day of the week using a code number and some rows with information for each day. When the user asks it, I want to send all the info from that certain day.

```
id      1         2         3

1       Info    Info     Info
2       Info    Info     Info
```

Until now I have this:

```
 // I know the know of the column and I want to compare it with the week code 
 //   of today so they can get the info for today
        $day=date(w);
        $conn = mysqlConnector();
        $cols = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM cond WHERE COLUMN_NAME = :col LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1');
        $cols->execute(array('col'=> $day));
```

I'm not sure if I should use COLUMN_NAME or how to use it, but this code doesn't work. Any idea? Thank you all

Comment: So you're trying to get all the information from say column 2? And it should return "Info" and "Info"?

Comment: Exactly! I use json to send it afterwards, but that's irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use column names as SQL bind variables.

It's not clear from your question what your column names are. *Edit* They seem to be `1`, `2`, etc.

You could use a SQL statement something like this:

```
SELECT `1` FROM cond LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1
```

To do this in php, you need to do something like this to create your query with

```
`1`
```

inserted into it as a literal.

```
$day = 1;
...
$cols = $conn->prepare("SELECT `$day` 
                          FROM cond 
                         WHERE COLUMN_NAME = :col
                         LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1");
$cols->execute();
```

You should be careful with this; make sure the value of $day can't get corrupted by a malicious user.

You should also be careful to make sure your column names, which happen to be integers, are surrounded by backticks:

```
SELECT 1 FROM cond
```

will give back a sequence of 1s, but

```
SELECT `1` FROM cond
```

will give back your data.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the question to make it more clear. The code gets the value of the column, so it has to return the contents of the column with that name.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and I get this error:

ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$day' in 'field list'

Comment: Try starting each column with an alphabetic character. I.e. d1, d2, d3. Then in your query make it `'d$day'`